# Multiple Radio button with text input

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can I enable the input type=text only if the "other" radio button is clicked.

```
<tr><td><font color='red' size='3'>*</font>CIVIL STATUS</td><td>:</td><td><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Single' required='required'> Single 
                                    <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Married' required='required'> Married 
                                    <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Annuled' required='required'> Annuled 
                                    <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Widowed' required='required'> Widowed 
                                    <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Seperated' required='required'> Seperated 
                                    <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' required='required' onclick='civstattxton()'> Others, 
                                    please specify here<input type='text' name='civstat' id='civstaton'></td>
                                    </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework e.g. JQuery?

Comment: No.. I'm just a newbie in Javascript.. I only know very basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to disable/enable the input based on the onclick event of each input. It's pretty messy but gets the job done:

```
  <tr><td><font color='red' size='3'>*</font>CIVIL STATUS</td><td>:</td><td><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Single' required='required'  onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");document.getElementById("civstaton").value = "";'> Single 
                                <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Married' required='required'  onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");document.getElementById("civstaton").value = "";'> Married 
                                <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Annuled' required='required'  onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");document.getElementById("civstaton").value = "";'> Annuled 
                                <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Widowed' required='required'  onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");document.getElementById("civstaton").value = "";'> Widowed 
                                <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' value='Seperated' required='required' onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");document.getElementById("civstaton").value = "";'> Seperated 
                                <br><input type='radio' name='civstat' required='required' onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").removeAttribute("disabled");'> Others, 
                                please specify here<input type='text' name='civstat' id='civstaton' disabled></td>
                                </tr>
```

Here is the demo: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/amiyaf/2/edit)

I recommend using a library like jQuery to attach an event handler to your radio buttons instead of this messy inline solution.

Comment: I intend to store this data in the database.. Will there be any conflict with this solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer so there can be no potential conflict such that a value would exist in the text input while another radio button is selected.

Comment: No problem, but if you are serious about JavaScript I recommend [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: I tested your solution and this is the way I want it work. Great. Thank you for your help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type='radio' name='civstat' required='required' 
       onclick='document.getElementById("civstaton").disabled = false'> 
       Others, please specify here
    <input type='text' name='civstat' id='civstaton' disabled>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nZQwf/)

Comment: I recommend you use [@dnapierata's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16350559/603127) because it reverts back and disable textbox again if any other radio button is clicked.

Comment: I tested it again but if I choose another radio button after I clicked the "Others" radio button the text field is still enable. Anyways thank you.. ^^